# Must I use an anonymous function with jquery's $.ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this:

```
$ajax = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'DBConnect.php',
    data: '',
    dataType: 'json', 
    success: function(data) {//I want to define this function externally
        var dataLength = data.length; ...
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
function myFunction(data) { 
    // do something 
}

$ajax = $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'DBConnect.php',
        data: '',
        dataType: 'json', 
        success: myFunction(data), 
...
```

When I try the above code it tells me data is not defined. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Must I use an anonymous function with jquery's $.ajax?

No

> When I try the above code it tells me data is not defined. How can I achieve this?

You are passing the *return value* of calling `myFunction`. Since it doesn't have a `return` statement, that value is `undefined`.

You need to pass a function instead.

```
success: myFunction,
```

Comment: Derp, that was what I needed. So by passing it "myFunction" I'm passing the function's definition and before I was actually calling the function and passing its return value, is this correct?